# Should I Update solution or Uninstall and Install?

Tags: feature-upgrade, update

I'm new to Sharepoint and need to optimize the powershell script for auto-installing the solution in Sharepoint server. Currently the pre-written script does following:

- Uninstall-SPSolution
- Remove-SPSolution
- Install-SPSolution

For each of these operations, it waits to stop timer job also. Will it make any issue if I replace all there using `Update-SPSolution` call? Will it update the xml and resource files with this call?

Answer (score 6):

In this scenario you have to be clear about ,

1. If the solution contains the same set of files and features , that
   is no new features or files been added in the existing Installed
   solution then you can use

   **Update-SPSolution** command

   2.If any new files been added or features been in the existing installed solution then you you need to foloow below steps:

**Uninstall-SPSolution** and **Install-SPSolution** cmdlets, respectively

Comment: Just to confirm, `Remove-SPSolution` will also be required?

Comment: yes if you've added new features or items you need to go with **Remove-SPSolution** and **Add-SPSolution**

Answer (score 3):

You have to add `ReplaceContent = "TRUE"` to each resource file
It will replace with updated file using `Update-SPSolution`

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: I found in Sharepoint logs that OWSTimer.exe resets the Aplication Pool when a solution is deployed, will it stop the application pool to get recycled?